# How to check object name by objectId?

Tags: apex, trigger, contact, object, if

```
trigger CreateTask on ContentVersion (after insert) 
{
List<Task> insertTask = new List<Task>();
Task newTask = new Task();
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult k=Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Id Contactapi = k.getKeyPrefix();
for(ContentVersion newCase : Trigger.new)
{
//Assign Content Version values to Task
if (Contactapi.getSobjectType() == Contact.SObjectType)
 {
     newTask.WhoId =  newCase.FirstPublishLocationId; 
   }
    else 
    {
      newTask.WhatId = newCase.FirstPublishLocationId; 
    }
insertTask.add(newTask);   
} 
}
```

This is what I try to create a task when document upload in Contact, Account, and Custom Objects. I need to check whether the object is contact or else to assign WhoId.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the Describe API. Just use the [`Id` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm)'s methods. Adapted from the documentation:

```
Contact a = new Contact(LastName = 'Test');
insert a;
Id myId = a.id;
System.assertEquals(Contact.SObjectType, myId.getSobjectType());
```

That's suitable for situations where you only have an Id value, such as working with polymorphic relationships - although you can also manage this in SOQL by filtering on the `Type` field across the relationship, e.g.,

```
SELECT Subject FROM Task WHERE Who.Type = 'Contact'
```

If you have not an Id but an sObject instance of unknown type, you can similarly ask it for `getSobjectType()`, or use an Apex [`switch on`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) construct to handle multiple types cleanly.

---

This code is tautological - it compares a value to itself.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult k=Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
      String Contactapi = k.getKeyPrefix();
    if(Contactapi == '003')
```

If you have a contact Id in a variable `myId`, you can ask if that Id represents a Contact with

```
if (myId.getSobjectType() == Contact.SObjectType)
```

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce uses `SmartIds`, which means the first three prefix will be same across all orgs for few standard objects.

For contact its `003`,

Here is the full [list](https://salesforcegenius.com/salesforce-object-id-prefixes-decoder-cereal-box-decoder-ring-salesforce-ids/)

Comment: This does not extend to custom objects where a different ID prefix can be assigned for the same object on different orgs.